# how to select data after a specific date in Sequelize.js

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize.js to handle data in MySQL, I want to find one data whose "updatedAt" is after a specific date, and I tried the code below:

```
const post = await Posts.findByPk(ctx.request.query.id);
const {updatedAt} = post;
const prev = await Posts.findOne({
      where: {
        updatedAt: {
          [Op.gt]: updatedAt
        }
      },
      attributes: ['id', 'title']
    });
```

It seems like [Op.gt] doesn't work, Sequelize.js returned a data with random date.

So, how can I select data after a specific date in Sequelize.js?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I messed up, the code is right, and Sequelize returned the right data, all I need is to tell Sequelize the order:

```
const post = await Posts.findByPk(ctx.request.query.id);
const {updatedAt} = post;
const prev = await Posts.findOne({
      where: {
        updatedAt: {
          [Op.gt]: updatedAt
        }
      },
      order: [['updatedAt', 'ASC']],
      attributes: ['id', 'title']
});
```